# Saving millions of OSM style maps as PNG images with Python on Windows

Tags: windows, python, openstreetmap

I have a CSV list of five million coordinates around which I have to render 100mx100m maps in PNG format. I want to use the default stylesheet from OpenStreetMaps, but without the text.

So far I only know how to extract PNG maps in Folium, but that is too slow and computationally expensive. I have looked at Maperitive, but I found a link saying that there's no straightforward way to replicate the OSM stylesheets in Maperitive. Also, unless I use one of the web maps they provide, part of the map simply returns nothing, even when using the stylesheets they provide. Let alone the fact that I cannot find any resources on how to script extracting multiple maps using Mapiritive.

I feel like there should be a better way of doing this.

Before I start digging to much into PyQGIS, what Windows software should I use?

I want a script that, for each row in my CSV file, returns a square map which represents approximately 100m x 100m.

Comment: Because of the high number of required images I strongly recommend to render the map image locally. Another relative simple and fast map renderer is [MapsForge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge). It's main focus is Android, but there are also tools available for map rendering on regular java on a desktop. Not sure about your Java skills, but using an IDE like IntelliJ executing Java is not much more complicated than Python. So writing a small Java program that reads the CSV file and renders the images would be my choice.